# how to differentiate input, focus and onblur text color?

Tags: javascript, forms, text, colors, onblur

i have a form where i would like to style the text color at the following stages:

1. on page load (defined in the css by 'input')
2. on input:focus (defined in the css by 'input:focus')
3. onblur (i don't know how to do this bit)

here is jsfiddle with my attempts.

http://jsfiddle.net/mT4cn/

it is working except the 'onblur' event reverts the text color back to that defined in the css by 'input'.

how can i make the 'onblur' text appear the same as the 'input:focus' text.

thank you.

**update**

i think i have figured it out:

change:

`<input name="email" id="email" value="your email" onFocus="clearText(this)"     onBlur="clearText(this)"/>`

to:

`<input name="email" id="email" value="your email" onFocus="clearText(this)" onBlur="clearText(this.className = 'onblurtext')"/>`

and add this to css:

`.onblurtext {
    color: #999 !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
}`

updated jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mT4cn/1/